# How to track token issuance

Tags: parachain, polkadot-js, balances

How would I track the token issuance of a parachain, using either the polkadot api or on-chain data?  Does anyone have a simple example?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is exposed in the state under `balances.totalIssuance`, so the following will work -

```js
const total = await api.query.balances.totalIssuance();

console.log(total.toString());
```

For the parachain connect to the parachain wss endpoint, for the relay chain connect to the relay wss endpoint.

Answer (score 1):

The total issuance of a Substrate chain is most commonly a storage item from the [Balances pallet](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/tree/master/frame/balances). Here's how you would find this value using Polkadot JS Apps:

1. Go to the [chain state for the chain you're querying](https://polkadot.js.org/apps/?rpc=wss%3A%2F%2Frpc.polkadot.io#/chainstate).
2. Select the `balances` pallet and the `totalIssuance` storage item.
3. Hit the " `+` " button on the right and you'll see some `u128` value appear.

For example, querying Polkadot's chain state:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

subscribe and trace

```
const unsub = await api.query.balances.totalIssuance((total) => {
  console.log(`Total issuance changed to ${total}`);
});
```